# macro in aux file

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, xr

I will show two similar files. First file

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\def\Site{left}
\section{Left Space}
\label{s:\Site Space}
\begin{equation}
\label{product from \Site}
a=bC
\end{equation}
\def\Site{right}
\section{\Site Space}
\label{s:\Site Space}
\begin{equation}
\label{product from \Site}
a=Cb
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

creates following aux file

```
\relax 
\newlabel{tocindent-1}{0pt}
\newlabel{tocindent0}{0pt}
\newlabel{tocindent1}{17.77782pt}
\newlabel{tocindent2}{0pt}
\newlabel{tocindent3}{0pt}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\tocsection {}{1}{Left Space}}{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{s:leftSpace}{{1}{1}}
\newlabel{product from left}{{1}{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\tocsection {}{2}{rightSpace}}{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{s:rightSpace}{{2}{1}}
\newlabel{product from right}{{2}{1}}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

Everything is fine. However small change in this code

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\def\Site{left}
\section{Left Space}
\label{s:\Site Space}
\begin{equation}
\label{product from \Site}
a=bC
\end{equation}
\def\Site{right}
\section{\Site Space}
\label{s:\Site Space}
\begin{equation}
\label{product from \Site}
a=Cb
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

creates little different aux file

```
\relax 
\providecommand\hyper@newdestlabel[2]{}
\providecommand\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\AtBeginDocument}
\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\global\let\oldnewlabel\newlabel
\gdef\newlabel#1#2{\newlabelxx{#1}#2}
\gdef\newlabelxx#1#2#3#4#5#6{\oldnewlabel{#1}{{#2}{#3}}}
\AtEndDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\let\newlabel\oldnewlabel
\fi}
\fi}
\global\let\hyper@last\relax 
\gdef\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument#1{#1}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToFields[1]{}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToCoFields[2]{}
\newlabel{tocindent-1}{0pt}
\newlabel{tocindent0}{0pt}
\newlabel{tocindent1}{17.77782pt}
\newlabel{tocindent2}{0pt}
\newlabel{tocindent3}{0pt}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\tocsection {}{1}{Left Space}}{1}{section.1}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{s:leftSpace}{{1}{1}{Left Space}{section.1}{}}
\newlabel{product from left}{{1}{1}{Left Space}{equation.1.1}{}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\tocsection {}{2}{rightSpace}}{1}{section.2}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{s:rightSpace}{{2}{1}{\Site Space}{section.2}{}}
\newlabel{product from right}{{2}{1}{\Site Space}{equation.2.2}{}}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

The question is how I can rewrite my code to make sure that macro will not appear in aux file. I like to use macro \externaldocument of package xr to show references to external document. However when I read into memory aux file with macro inside I get error.

Comment: Which macros are you not wanting to appear in your aux file?  The only ones I see are put there by hyperref (I think so that if you remove hyperref you won't have an error on the next run).  What error are you getting?  If your referencing document also using hyperref?

Comment: I want that secoond aux file will not have macro which I defined like it happens in first file. For example in this code I do not wanr to see macro \Site in aux file, However I need this macro in TeX file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nameref uses the gettitlestring package to store the title of sectioning commands. You can change the method used to `expand`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}


\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\GetTitleStringSetup{expand}

\begin{document}
\def\Site{left}
\section{Left Space}
\label{s:\Site Space}
\begin{equation}
\label{product from \Site}
a=bC
\end{equation}
\def\Site{right}
\section{\Site Space}
\label{s:\Site Space}
\begin{equation}
\label{product from \Site}
a=Cb
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This will then give in the aux:

```
\newlabel{s:rightSpace}{{2}{1}{rightSpace}{section.2}{}}
\newlabel{product from right}{{2}{1}{rightSpace}{equation.2.2}{}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This, as pointed out by Ukraine, doesn’t fix the problem, it just expands the label text which is expanded anyway.

Adding `hyperref` is not a small change. It redefines the label and sectioning commands to add the hyperlinks. Your calls to `\Site` are being captured as unexpanded tokens by the new `hyperref` `label`.

The simplest solution I can think of is to wrap the label command that expands the argument before passing it to label, so something like this:

```latex
\def\wrappedlabel#1{%
  {\edef\arg{#1}%
  \expandafter\label\expandafter{\arg}}%
}
```

Used like the original label command.

The gist of this is to use an `edef` to expand the content of the argument fully before using the standard `expandafter` sequence to expand it before being read by `label`. We need the `edef` to deal with situations where you want `\Site` located somewhere other than the first token in the label text.

Comment: this doesn't change a thing, the argument of a label is expanded anyway.

Comment: Yes, but hyperref calls something called newlabel. Some argument is being written unexoanded to a call to newlabel. See the line two up from the bottom. That’s what they’re having trouble with.

Comment: I know that (I maintain hyperref+nameref). But your code doesn't solve that problem.

Comment: Ha, well you should have led with that. I was going to ask you why it doesn’t work, but I see it. The unexpanded text is collected from the section name, not the label.

Comment: Should I delete this or leave it for posterity? Not sure what the rules suggest. I should probably stop answering questions at 4AM.

Comment: Using \GetTitleStringSetup{expand} is good idea. It changes the aux file. But it also changes the title of section

Comment: I also do not understand why discussion should be deleted before it resolve the issue

Comment: I was not right.  \GetTitleStringSetup{expand} works perfect. I played with code and see that I get what I want. Thank you

Comment: Great, don’t forget to accept Ulrike’s answer! (I also meant delete my incorrect answer, not your question!)